# how not to increase view count when someone sending more than one GET request

Tags: python, django, get, ip

i am trying to count view of blog posts.

here is my models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='post_author')
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=264,verbose_name='Put a Title')
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='category',default=None)
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=264,unique=True,null=True,allow_unicode=True)
    blog_content=models.TextField(verbose_name='what is on your mind?')
    blog_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images',verbose_name='Image')
    publish_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    view_count=models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0,blank=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish_date',)
```

here's how i am increasing the view count of a post for every GET request

```
def blog_details(request, slug):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        blog.view_count =blog.view_count+1    
        blog.save()
    *skipping giving the whole(irrelevant to the question) code of the function*
```

Now how can i increase view count of a post for the first GET request from a user(registered or anonymous) by 1. If they send more get request view count would not be increased.
Pardom mistake and THANK YOU in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the kind of use case that session variables are designed for. They will store info about the visit for a period

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    #we use .get so it returns None rather than a key error if not set
    visited = request.session.get('visited')
    if not visited:
        blog.view_count =blog.view_count+1    
        blog.save()
        #we've updated the count so we make sure the code doesn't run next time.
        request.session['visited'] = True
```

[Session variable docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/) - you may find the Browser-length sessions vs. persistent sessions section relevant to your interests